# Prove $C(X)$ is a Banach algebra by first showing for all $x$, $\vert fg(x)\vert \le \Vert f \Vert \cdot \Vert g \Vert$

Tags: banach-spaces, banach-algebras

I have to prove that $C(X)$ is a Banach algebra. I know that $C(X)$ is a Banach space and that $\langle C(X),+,*\rangle$ is a ring. I know I need to show that $\Vert fg\Vert \le \Vert f \Vert \cdot \Vert g \Vert$. The advice from my professor was: to show $\Vert fg \Vert \le \Vert f \Vert \cdot \Vert g\Vert$, it is enough to show,

1. For all $x$, $\vert fg(x)\vert \le \Vert f \Vert \cdot \Vert g \Vert$,
2. since 1. shows $\Vert f \Vert \cdot \Vert g \Vert$ is an upper bound of $\vert fg(x)\vert$ and the result will follow from the definition of the supremum.

I'm stuck. He said there was a small step or two to show 1, then expand 2 to finish the proof. The only other information we have is that $\Vert f \Vert = \sup \vert f(x)\vert$ for all $f \in C(X)$. I'm looking for advice on how to approach this.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Also, please use MathJax throughout.

Comment: @Shaun I've updated the title, but I did use MathJax for everything.

Comment: That title isn't any better. Also, no, you didn't.

Comment: @Shaun Then what would you recommend, and where didn't I use it?

Comment: See [this revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4693831/3).

Comment: I have edited the title.

Comment: @Shaun thank you, and I'm sorry I missed that inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that for any $x\in X$,

$$\lvert(fg)(x)\rvert=\lvert f(x)\rvert\cdot\lvert g(x)\rvert\leq\sup_{\xi\in X}\lvert f(\xi)\rvert\cdot\sup_{\eta\in X}\lvert g(\eta)\rvert=\lVert f\rVert\cdot\lVert g\rVert.$$

Thus $\lVert f\rVert\cdot\lVert g\rVert$ is an upper bound of $\lvert (fg)(x)\rvert$ for $x\in X$, and consequently the inequality also holds for the *least* upper bound, i.e.

$$\lVert fg\rVert=\sup_{x\in X}\lvert (fg)(x)\rvert\leq\lVert f\rVert\cdot\lVert g\rVert.$$

Comment: Thank you. I just want to make sure I'm clear. This is just showing 1. correct? I need to take this and expand upon it to show that it is a Banach algebra.

Comment: @Tacosi it's both 1 and 2. In particular, it shows that $\lVert fg\rVert\leq\lVert f\rVert\cdot\lVert g\rVert$, which is what you wanted to show, no?

Comment: yes it is. Thank you. My professor just made it seem like it would be more involved when he said to expand on 2. Thank you for your help.